# Grouping nested object properties

Tags: javascript, loops, nested-object

I have this nested Object:

```
{
  1: { one: { a: 5, b: 6, c: 7, d: 8 } },
  2: { one: { a: 6, b: 9, c: 10, d: 12, e: 1 } },
  3: { one: { a: 3, b: 4, c: 9 } },
}
```

Required output:

```
{
  one: {
    a: [5, 6, 3]
    b: [6, 9, 4]
    c: [7, 10, 9]
    d: [12]
    e: [1]
  }
}
```

Tried nested queries but failed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about nested queries. You just need nested loops.

Comment: Thank you very much all of you for your answers I really appreciate each one of you for your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take. A series of nested for [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops. Tried to optimize for readability.

```js
const object = {
  1: { one: { a: 5, b: 6, c: 7, d: 8 } },
  2: { one: { a: 6, b: 9, c: 10, d: 12, e: 1 } },
  3: { one: { a: 3, b: 4, c: 9 } },
};

const result = {};

for (const group in object) {
  for (const num in object[group]) {
    if (!result[num]) {
      result[num] = {};
    }
    for (const letter in object[group][num]) {
      if (!result[num][letter]) {
        result[num][letter] = [];
      }
      result[num][letter].push(object[group][num][letter])
    }
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested loops. You don't care about the keys of the top-level object, so loop over its values with `Object.values()`. Then loop over the keys and values of the nested objects. Create nested objects in the result when needed, then add the values.

```js
const obj1 = { 
  1: {one:{ a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8}},
  2: {one:{ a:6,b:9,c:10,d:12,e:1}},
  3: {one:{a:3,b:4,c:9}}
};

let result = {};
Object.values(obj1).forEach(val1 => {
  Object.entries(val1).forEach(([key2, val2]) => {
    if (!result.hasOwnProperty(key2)) {
      result[key2] = {};
    }
    res2 = result[key2];
    Object.entries(val2).forEach(([key3, val3]) => {
      if (!res2.hasOwnProperty(key3)) {
        res2[key3] = [val3];
      } else {
        res2[key3].push(val3);
      }
    });
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach is doing two groups:

- group the first top-level object `keys` and get their values store them as value of an array.
- group the keys of the arrays value *(in the previous group)*

```js
let objs = {
  1: { one: { a: 5, b: 6, c: 7, d: 8 } },
  2: { one: { a: 6, b: 9, c: 10, d: 12, e: 1 } },
  3: { one: { a: 3, b: 4, c: 9 } },
};
let groupByKey = {};
for (const obj of Object.values(objs)) {
  let [key, inerObjs] = Object.entries(obj)[0];
  groupByKey[key] ??= [];
  groupByKey[key].push(Object.entries(inerObjs));
}

let result = {};
for (const [k, arrs] of Object.entries(groupByKey)) {
  let group = {};
  for (const obj of arrs.flat()) {
    if (!group.hasOwnProperty(obj[0])) {
      group[obj[0]] = [obj[1]];
    } else {
      group[obj[0]].push(obj[1]);
    }
  }
  result[k] = group;
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive option that works for objects of arbitrary depth. Here calling it with an empty object as target and spreading the `Object.values` of your input in order to skip the top level properties as per your expected output.

```js
function groupProperties(target, ...objects) {
  for (const obj of objects) {
    for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      if (typeof v === 'object') {
        groupProperties((target[k] ??= {}), v);
      }
      else {
        (target[k] ??= []).push(v);
      }
    }
  }

  return target;
}

const input = { 1: { one: { a: 5, b: 6, c: 7, d: 8 } }, 2: { one: { a: 6, b: 9, c: 10, d: 12, e: 1 } }, 3: { one: { a: 3, b: 4, c: 9 } }, };

const result = groupProperties({}, ...Object.values(input));

console.log(result);
```